# having error for missing left parenthesis?

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Transaction
(Portfolio_Number NUMBER(7,0) CONSTRAINT NN_Portfolio_Number NOT NULL,
                            CONSTRAINT FK_Portfolio_Number FOREIGN KEY
                            (Portfolio_Number) REFERENCES Portfolio(Portfolio_Number),
                            CONSTRAINT PK_Portfolio_Number PRIMARY KEY,
Stock_Code VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT NN_Stock_Code NOT NULL,
                            CONSTRAINT FK_Stock_Code FOREIGN KEY
                            (Stock_Code) REFERENCES Stock(Stock_Code),
                            CONSTRAINT PK_Stock_Code PRIMARY KEY,
Transaction_Date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
                    CONSTRAINT PK_Transaction_Date PRIMARY KEY
                    CONSTRAINT NN_Transaction_Date NOT NULL,
Exchange_Code VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT NN_Exchange_Code NOT NULL,
                        CONSTRAINT FK_Exchange_Code FOREIGN KEY
                        (Exchange_Code) REFERENCES Exchange(Exchange_Code),
Broker_Number NUMBER(7,0) CONSTRAINT NN_Broker_Number NOT NULL,
                        CONSTRAINT FK_Broker_Number FOREIGN KEY
                        (Broker_Number) REFERENCES Broker(Broker_Number),
Buy_Sell CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT NN_Buy_Sell NOT NULL,
Quantity NUMBER(7,0) CONSTRAINT CK_Quantity CHECK (Quantity > 0)
                    CONSTRAINT NN_Quantity NOT NULL,
Price_Per_Share NUMBER(6,2) CONSTRAINT NN_Price_Per_Share NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you got lost in too many **CONSTRAINT**s scattered throughout that piece of code.

- a table can have only one primary key constraint; you have 3 of them. If it is a composite primary key, all columns should be placed into the same `CONSTRAINT` clause (see my example)
- you can't mix constraints with columns; if you use them, put all those outline constraints to the end of the script (like I did)

I can't run it as I miss all tables you're referencing, but - this code is formatted properly so I hope it should compile.

```
CREATE TABLE Transaction
(
   Portfolio_Number  NUMBER (7, 0) CONSTRAINT NN_Portfolio_Number NOT NULL,
   Stock_Code        NUMBER (7, 0) CONSTRAINT NN_Stock_Code NOT NULL,
   Transaction_Date  DATE
                        DEFAULT SYSDATE
                        CONSTRAINT NN_Transaction_Date NOT NULL,
   Exchange_Code     VARCHAR2 (4) CONSTRAINT NN_Exchange_Code NOT NULL,
   Broker_Number     NUMBER (7, 0) CONSTRAINT NN_Broker_Number NOT NULL,
   Buy_Sell          CHAR (1) CONSTRAINT NN_Buy_Sell NOT NULL,
   Quantity          NUMBER (7, 0)
                        CONSTRAINT CK_Quantity CHECK (Quantity > 0)
                        CONSTRAINT NN_Quantity NOT NULL,
   Price_Per_Share   NUMBER (6, 2) CONSTRAINT NN_Price_Per_Share NOT NULL,
   --
   CONSTRAINT PK_Transaction_Date PRIMARY KEY
      (portfolio_number, transaction_date, stock_code),
   CONSTRAINT FK_Portfolio_Number FOREIGN KEY
      (Portfolio_Number)
       REFERENCES Portfolio (Portfolio_Number),
   CONSTRAINT FK_Stock_Code FOREIGN KEY
      (Stock_Code)
       REFERENCES Stock (Stock_Code),
   CONSTRAINT FK_Exchange_Code FOREIGN KEY
      (Exchange_Code)
       REFERENCES Exchange (Exchange_Code),
   CONSTRAINT FK_Broker_Number FOREIGN KEY
      (Broker_Number)
       REFERENCES Broker (Broker_Number)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a primary key without specifying column name

```
, CONSTRAINT PK_Portfolio_Number PRIMARY KEY,
```

which is wrong. The right would be something like that

```
, CONSTRAINT PK_Portfolio_Number PRIMARY KEY(Portfolio_Number),
```

Next thing to note is you're trying to create 2 primary keys for same table which is impossible. If you need a primary key to be for both columns, you need to specify them in the same statement

```
, CONSTRAINT PK_Portfolio_Number PRIMARY KEY(Portfolio_Number, Stock_Code),
```